# How to set alarm on Given time in android

Tags: android

```
public class SchedulerSetupReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String APP_TAG = "com.hascode.android";

    private static final int EXEC_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;
    DBhelper dbhelper;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context ctx, final Intent intent) {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "SchedulerSetupReceiver.onReceive() called");
        dbhelper = new DBhelper(ctx);


        String [] ID=dbhelper.FetchAllID();
        String[] time=dbhelper.FetchAlltime();

        for(int k=0;k<ID.length;k++)
        {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SchedulerEventReceiver.class); // explicit
                                                                    // intent
        PendingIntent intentExecuted = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                now.getTimeInMillis(), EXEC_INTERVAL, intentExecuted);


        }

    }

}
```

This is my code  for repeating alarm in each 20 second but i want  Alarm should set at 3.30 , 4.50, 8.30 can any one Suggest me  what i will change in Set repeating method  so that Alarm will Broad cast Each 3.30 , 4.50,8.30 so that i can test some Condition in broadcast .

Comment: set 3 separate repeating alarms each for 24 hours

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/iDRAvSGaGBCBYZMv6aT9JQ  i have use this But i am facing Problem to to set my time which is coming from my Local Database time[]

Comment: your times doesn't follow any pattern. you should use separate alarm for each and not in a for loop

Comment: but we have time is coming Dynamically how to Use Se-prate alarm

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code. I think this will help you

NotificationReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "notificationMessage";
    public static int NOW_NOTIFICATION = 101;

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        this.context = context;

        String message = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //Define sound URI
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, EmptyActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        final DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
        int color = 0xffffaa00;
//        int color1 = context.getColor(R.color.notificatinBackgroundColor);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.festi_push_message_small);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setContentTitle("Notification Sample");
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentText(message);
        builder.setSound(soundUri);
        builder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000);
        builder.setColor(color);

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(102938, notification);

        cancelNotification(NOW_NOTIFICATION);
        createNewNotification();
    }

    public void cancelNotification(int requestCode) {
        try {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createNewNotification() {

        //Set next alarm date time (dynamically coming date and time) here
        final DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.now();
        dateTime1.hourOfDay().setCopy(7);
        dateTime1.minuteOfHour().setCopy(30);
        dateTime1.secondOfMinute().setCopy(00);
        final Calendar calendarNotifiedTime1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarNotifiedTime1.set(Calendar.HOUR, dateTime1.getHourOfDay());
        calendarNotifiedTime1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dateTime1.getMinuteOfHour());
        calendarNotifiedTime1.set(Calendar.SECOND, dateTime1.getSecondOfMinute());
        calendarNotifiedTime1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Sample Alert");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, NOW_NOTIFICATION, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        cancelNotification(NOW_NOTIFICATION);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarNotifiedTime1.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    }

}
```

Comment: DateTIme() class not found

Comment: I am using joda datetime.